Is it allowed to cast a pointer of first member to the enclosing type?
According to the C Standard, it is allowed to cast a pointer to a struct to a pointer of the type of the first member of this struct.
However, is it allowed to do the opposite?
Consider the following example:
//texture.h
typedef struct HAL_TEXTURE {
  size_t w;
  size_t h;
} HAL_TEXTURE;

HAL_TEXTURE* CreateTexture(size_t w, size_t h, void* data);
void BindTexture(HAL_TEXTURE* texture);

// d3d10/texture.c linked on windows
typedef struct D3D10_TEXTURE { // not visible outside of this translation unit
  HAL_TEXTURE agnostic;
  ID3D10ShaderResourceView* srv;
} D3D10_TEXTURE;

HAL_TEXTURE* CreateTexture(size_t w, size_t h, void* data) {
  D3D10_TEXTURE* texture = calloc(...);
  //...//
  return (HAL_TEXTURE*)texture; // ok, according to standard
}

void BindTexture(HAL_TEXTURE* texture) {
  D3D10_TEXTURE* tex = (D3D10_TEXTURE*)texture; // is this allowed?
  //...//
  //access D3D10 specific stuff here
}

// ogl/texture.c linked on linux
typedef struct OGL_TEXTURE { // not visible outside of TU
  HAL_TEXTURE agnostic;
  GLint id;
} OGL_TEXTURE;

HAL_TEXTURE* CreateTexture(size_t w, size_t h, void* data) {
  OGL_TEXTURE* texture = calloc(...);
  //...//
  return (HAL_TEXTURE*)texture;
}

void BindTexture(HAL_TEXTURE* texture) {
  OGL_TEXTURE* tex = (OGL_TEXTURE*)texture;
  //...//
  //access OpenGL specific stuff here
}

Can I safely cast HAL_TEXTURE* (which is the first member of D3D10_TEXTURE and OGL_TEXTURE) to a pointer of the enclosing type?

You can do it but why? Is it hard to write xxx->w?

@i486: It's extremely important for use cases like CPython's object system, where all objects start with a PyObject as their first member, and PyObject * pointers need to be cast to and from pointers to the enclosing struct type.

Here, accessing texture->w is simple enough with a HAL_TEXTURE *, but if you want to access srv or id, you need to get a D3D10_TEXTURE * or an OGL_TEXTURE * first.

It is allowed to derive a pointer to anywhere in the object from a pointer to anywhere else in the object.

Yes. According to the ISO C standard (C2x working draft from 2019) (https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2347.pdf), section 6.7.2.1 §15:


Within a structure object, the non-bit-field members and the units in which bit-fields reside have
addresses that increase in the order in which they are declared. A pointer to a structure object,
suitably converted, points to its initial member (or if that member is a bit-field, then to the unit in
which it resides), and vice versa. There may be unnamed padding within a structure object, but not
at its beginning.



@EricPostpischil thank you, I'll update the reference to the actual standard.

It's allowed. That's what the "and vice versa" part is for. §6.5 paragraph 7 doesn't forbid accessing the members; the member access expression will have the correct type.

Thanks @user2357112, I'll revert the edit.

Specifically, a struct is an "aggregate type" and 6.5 §7 allows a struct member to be lvalue accessed by a struct type having the same type as that member as one of its objects. Which might seem like a crazy thing to do, but the reason for this rule is that compilers aren't allowed to assume that some int remains unchanged when the code has only updated a struct by pointer access, in case that struct is containing an int member. These would be the various "pointer aliasing rules".
