Mutual conversion of pointers to a structure and its first member, and strict aliasing in C
I have structure
typedef struct {
  int   i;
  float f;
} S;

The rules for mutual conversions between pointers to a structure and its first member say that I can write like this
S s;
int *pInt = (int *)&s;

However, is it legal according to the C standard to convert an arbitrary pointer to an integer back into a pointer to a structure, and then access its other members?
int *pInt = ...; // some pointer to int
...
S *pS = (S *)pInt;

float f = pS->f;
pS->f   = 10;

I tried to find answers to this question in the standard, but did not find a direct answer.
I have a guarantee that the place where pInt points to actually contains a structure (and in fact, structures can be of different types and sizes, but they all have the same first int member - this is how I determine what kind of structure it is), but I want to understand if there is undefined behavior here?

This strange description is because I greatly simplified my original problem.
What do I really mean? I have a microcontroller that has parameter structures (of different lengths and types) in internal memory. I put pointers to all these structures in an array - for this, all structures have the same beginning - a marker element.

The order of pointers can be completely different from device to device, so it is not possible to know in advance which specific structure is addressed by the Nth element of the array (from the outside observer). An external observer (computer) requests parameters by sending the index of this array.

Accordingly, I have a protocol processing loop in which I go into the array using this index, select the address of the structure from there, and then... I need to know what its format is in order to correctly read its fields and correctly serialize them back to the computer.

Common initial sequences only apply to struct values of a union: http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.2.3p6

I don't know the answer, but I think you have two different questions here, which might have opposite answers.  One question is for casting from int* to S*, where S is the dynamic type of that location in memory. Another question is for casting to S1*, where S1 is an unrelated struct which also has int as first field. You can [edit] your question to clarify.

This is pretty useful, as you can simulate inheritance on structs in c. But you must be careful on which compiler/version you're using. Older ones, I believe I had read this somewhere, they might try to optimize the order of struct members in order to reduce its total size in bytes. But, I never ran into any problems with the newest versions of gcc.

@AndrewHenle — Note also §6.7.2 ¶15-16.

@CarlHR The order of struct members is fixed by the standard.


I have a guarantee that the place where pInt points to actually contains a structure (and in fact, structures can be of different types and sizes, but they all have the same first int member - this is how I determine what kind of structure it is), but I want to understand if there is undefined behavior here?

Yes, the behavior is undefined. If pInt points to memory where there is a structure of type Q (meaning that memory was declared as a Q or has been given an effective type of Q by copying bytes representing a Q into it) and Q is not S and does not contain an S member, then the behavior of using ((S *) pInt)->member to read a member of the Q structure is not defined by the C standard.
It is not clear why you are asking this question. If you have a pInt that is a pointer to an int, and that int tells you what type of structure is there, then simply examine *pInt to decide what type to use for later access. You could have a switch statement or other code that uses ((S *) pInt)->member if the int indicates S or ((Q *) pInt)->member if the int indicates Q, and so on. Why would you want to access the memory as an S type if the memory does not contain an S?
In response to a comment, here is sample code to access the structure after identifying its type. We presume some constants CodeForStructureN have been defined, each identifying a corresponding structure type named StructureN:
void foo(void *buffer)
{
    switch ((int *) buffer)
    {
        case CodeForStructure0:
            Structure0 *S = buffer;
            … Use S to access Structure0 members, as in S->member …
            break;

        case CodeForStructure1:
            Structure1 *S = buffer;
            … Use S to access Structure1 members, as in S->member …
            break;

        case CodeForStructure2:
            Structure2 *S = buffer;
            … Use S to access Structure2 members, as in S->member …
            break;

        …

        default:
            fprintf(stderr, "Unrecognized structure code.\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}


Before accessing the entire structure, I want to dereference *pInt. Yes, there will be some switch(*pInt) {...}. But what to do then? So I determined that the *pInt value equal to 10 encodes a structure of the format struct Str10 {int structType; float f; char const *name;}. In the case branch of swtch() I want to read the field f (because I know that the storage at pInt is in the format of a Str10. That's why I want to write further float f = ((Str10 *)pInt)->f; and I ask how legal this is.

@EvgenyIlyin: I have added sample code showing you how to write a switch statement for this.

@EvgenyIlyin The issue here may be your use of the word arbitrary in "an arbitrary pointer to an integer". That implies that at the time of the cast to S, the int pointer you are trying to cast is not necessarily pointing to an instance of S, but possibly to some other struct type with int first member or even just an plain int. I believe that Eric Postpischil might have written a different answer if you had not used the word "arbitrary"

I wrote "arbitrary" because the type of the actual structure, which has this int as its first member, will be known only after identifying the contents of this *pInt. After all, depending on the code contained in *pInt, these can be structures of different types, and the compiler cannot determine in advance which one. Of course, only I (the author) knows what will happen if I do not correctly identify the code and access a memory location using the wrong structure pattern, but this is not undefined behavior from the point of view of the C language.

But from the point of view of aliasing rules, you cannot dereference the pointer ((SomeStruct *)pInt)->... even though pInt numerically points to the beginning of the SomeStruct structure object.

@EvgenyIlyin: You can deference the pointer its type is “pointer to S” and the effective type of the object it points to is S. So checking the type first and then using the appropriate type works. The question you posted asks about using a pointer of type “pointer to S” when there are different types of structures at the pointed-to memory.

Looks like my question was misunderstood. I'll try again.
According to 6.7.2.1 of the standard,
Within a structure object, the non-bit-field members and the units in which bit-fields reside have addresses that increase in the order in which they are declared. A pointer to a structure object, suitably converted, points to its initial member (or if that member is a bit-field, then to the unit in which it resides), and vice versa. There may be unnamed padding within a structure object, but not at its beginning.

However, according to 6.5 of the standard,
An object shall have its stored value accessed only by an lvalue expression that has one of the following types:

a type compatible with the effective type of the object,
...
an aggregate or union type that includes one of the aforementioned types among its members (including, recursively, a member of a subaggregate or contained union), or
a character type.


Here they say that behavior is defined
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1185946/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D1%8B-%D0%BA-%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%83-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B8%D1%82-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%B2-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B5?newreg=89e0a4c4c7a64ea88d2d94ea25c937ab

@EvgenyIlyin: No, they do not say the behavior described here is defined. That question has a structure struct kodik_api_countries_t in which the first member is libkodik_api_object_t s_api_base and a pointer to the outer structure is converted to a pointer to the type of its first member and then used to access that first member. That is not even aliasing; the inner structure is accessed as its declared type. The question you posted here asked, apparently, about accessing a structure of one type using a structure of another type. Those are different situations.

@EricPostpischil: I found another topic where I find confirmation that the behavior is defined... Otherwise, how to interpret the words "...and vice versa"?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78730041/is-it-allowed-to-cast-a-pointer-of-first-member-to-the-enclosing-type

@EvgenyIlyin: That question does not ask about using the pointer to access a structure at all. It only asks about converting the pointer.

@EvgenyIlyin: Here it is simply. You have a pointer P of type int. It points to certain memory. That memory has been filled with a structure of type A, B, C, D, or other. Each of these structures has a first member of type int. The int tells you which type of structure it is. You can use *P to read the int, and then, if the structure is of type A, you can use ((A *) P)->member to access it. If it is of type B, you can use ((B *) P)->member, and so on for C, D, and other types. As long as you use the right type to access it, the behavior is defined.

@EvgenyIlyin: If you use the wrong type, the behavior is not defined. There may be certain circumstances where using the wrong type would still have defined behavior, such as when a suitable union is also declared, but they do not apply in the particular circumstances that appear to be involved here. The solution to what you want to do is simple, and code for it is given in this answer: Test the int, then use a switch to select code that uses the right type to access the structure.

@EvgenyIlyin: One issue that may have caused some confusion is that you may have phrased the question unclear. You asked about accessing a structure using the type S but said the memory would hold “different types.” If the structure has a different type and you access it with type S, the behavior is not defined. But you may have intended to say that the structure would have different types A, B, C, and so on, and you would access it with type A, type B, type C, and so on, using the right type once the type had been determined. In that case, the behavior is defined.

@EvgenyIlyin: Again, this is really quite simple: Use the correct type to access the structure. The correct type is the actual type of the structure.

@Eric Postpischil: This is what I mean by “the behavior is defined”, that I can use the notation ((A *) P)->member (as opposed to strict aliasing rules being violated by such access in general).
The compiler does not know in advance where P actually points (this will be taken into switch(*P )).
I mean that in such a pointer conversion there is no UB, based on which the compiler can generate completely incorrect code or throw it out. Did you mean "the behavior is undefined" - the processor instructions are correct, but the result may be undefined? These are different things...

@EricPostpischil: For example,
int i;
float *pf = (float *)&i ; // OK
float f = *pf; // an obvious violation of strict aliasing, the behavior is not defined at the level of the language standard: a real compiler, knowing this, can simply throw out a piece of code without generating any instructions.
I wanted guarantees that during mutual casts between pointers to a structure and its first member there would be no such tricks, because This is not undefined behavior at the language level (even though at the system level it can lead to UB).

Eric Postpischil's solution is a good one, but I think Andrew Henle's mention of unions begs for expansion.
typedef struct {
  int type;
  union {
    struct a_s a;
    struct b_s b;
    struct c_s c;
  } u;
} s_t;
...
  s_t x;

  get_s_msg(&x);

  switch (x.type) {
    case 0: {
      struct a_s *a = &x.u.a;
      printf("a->a_field=%d\n", a->a_field);
      break;
    }
...

An advantage of using the union is you can declare a buffer of that type and it will be the right size to hold any of the underlying structure types. Another advantage is better compile-time type checking which can find some bugs early. Many would say the resulting code is more readable.
A disadvantage is wasted space if you need to hold many of them, and they are of greatly varying size; they'll all be the worst-case size. Also the union is pretty much defeated for a message type that is itself of variable length.

The way the aliasing rules for C are written does not include any general provision allowing an object of structure or union type to be accessed via lvalue of any non-character primitive type, though it does provide for accessing an object of member type using an lvalue of the struct or union type.
This would make sense if one viewed as so obvious that it shouldn't need saying the notion that lvalues that are freshly visibly derived from lvalues of other type should be assumed capable of aliasing the same things as the former lvalue.  A compiler that isn't being willfully obtuse would be able to recognize that even though foo->intArray[2] = 3; would be equivalent to *(foo->intArray+3) = 3; and the left operand is a dereferenced int*, it is freshly visibly derived from an lvalue of *foo's type.  If a structure has a member of type int, it would be rare for code to access that storage through the structure, and then via an int*, without an intervening operation that takes the address of the structure member, but it would be common for code to access the storage via int* and then through the structure, without any intervening access.
The authors of the Standard made no effort to consider all possible corner cases and ensure that the Standard mandated useful treatment.  Given that it relies upon compilers to exercise common sense with such constructs as structPtr->intArray[index], even though they violate the type-based access constraint, and given that compilers almost invariably support a dialect where the notion of type-based aliasing doesn't exist, treating code which does anything tricky as requiring the use of such a dialect is wiser than trying to guess what usage patterns a compiler will or will not support.
